# Setting options for VLC ActiveX Plugin

Tags: c#, winforms, video, activex, vlc

I was able to use the [vlc activex plugin](https://wiki.videolan.org/ActiveX/) (version 1 and 2) in a c#.net application to display videos. It runs nicely, but I can't set any options.

Here's the code:

```
string options = "--brightness=2"; // I also tried ":brightness"
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("file:///"+ filePath1, options, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListReplaceAndGo, 0);
axVLCPlugin1.play();
```

This is for version 1. Version 2 gives the same results. The "options" do not have any effect on the displayed video.

The documentation says that most command line options will work, but I can't get any to work.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I achieve this without using activex plugin, but directly with libvlc functions:
1. add the libvlc.dll, libvlccore.dll and vlc plugins direction to c# project direction.
2. use DllImport to import vlc functions into C# code.
3. call the vlc functions in C#, and it is possible to add vlc options.

The code in http://jcwshih.blogspot.de/2012_07_01_archive.html could be helpful.

Best regards

Comment: Thanks, it worked. But it opens a new window for the vlc player. I want to have the player in the main window. Can this be done?

Comment: OK, I found it. Add a panel to the form, and use vlc.SetRenderWindow((int)panel1.Handle); Thank you very much for your help