# Hide Video Controls in VLC

Tags: c#, vlc, libvlc

I want to hide play/pause, volume buttons from VLC ActiveX plugin control I am using in my windows form application.

I tries this solution but it is not giving me desired result on hover.

```
string[] args = new string[] { "--intf dummy" };
axVLCPlugin1.addTarget("rtsp://192.168.1.117:554/live", args, AXVLC.VLCPlaylistMode.VLCPlayListInsert, 0);
axVLCPlugin1.play();
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19138984/setting-options-for-vlc-activex-plugin

Answer (score 1):

https://wiki.videolan.org/Documentation:WebPlugin/#Optional_elements

```
axVLCPlugin1.toolbar = false;
```

Comment: This option is not available.

Comment: It will be available only if you will use "new" IVLCControl2 ( http://git.videolan.org/?p=npapi-vlc.git;a=blob;f=activex/axvlc.idl;hb=HEAD#l677 )

Comment: I'm using Delphi and had the same issue. Works with `NameOfYourVLCPluginComponent.ControlInterface.Toolbar := False;` Same with Branding: `NameOfYourVLCPluginComponent.ControlInterface.Branding := False;`

Answer (score 0):

Use the

```
 string[] args = new string[] {
      "-I", "dummy", "--ignore-config",
      @"--plugin-path=C:\Program Files (x86)\VideoLAN\VLC\plugins",
      "--vout-filter=deinterlace", "--deinterlace-mode=blend"
 };
```

parameter

[source](http://www.helyar.net/2009/libvlc-media-player-in-c-part-2/)